# Proving an interval is a subset of the image of an function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Question:

$f :\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ via  $ f(x)= \dfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ . Prove $[0,1) \subseteq f(\mathbb R)$.

Note:  $f(\mathbb R)$ is the same as image $f$.

Calculus is not allowed. No limits, intermediate value theorem or derivatives

My attempt:

Pick $ y \in [0,1) $. We need to show there exists a $ z \in \mathbb R $ such that $ y = f(z) $.

$$ y = \frac{z^2}{1 + z^2} $$

$$ y(1+z^2) = z^2 $$

$$ y + yz^2 - z^2 = 0 $$

Now how do I show that $ 0\le y<1 $ using the above equation?

Comment: I think it is way easier than you attempt it: the expression $\;\cfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}\;$ is clearly positive and also $\;\le1\;$ for **any** $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ , and it vanishes for $\;x=0\;$ ...voila!

Comment: But I have to formally prove it

Comment: The above is very formally...in fact, I think it is basic high school level: any real number squared is non negative, and any positive number divided by a number bigger than itself yields a number that is less than one. If you insist in "more formality", you can do $$\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}<1\iff x^2<1+x^2\iff 0<1$$and hopefully the last inequality is trivial, and also the fact that the fraction is always non-negative...

Comment: But this implies that the image is a subset of [0,1). I need to show that [0,1) is a subset of the image.

Comment: To complete the argument look at the limit at $\infty$ and use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Well, $$y+yz^2-z^2=0\iff y+z^2(y-1)=0\iff z^2=-\frac{y}{y-1} $$ Both members are non negative (because $0\le y< 1$) so $$z=\pm\sqrt{\frac{y}{y-1}}\in\mbox{dom}(f)$$ In this manner we show that for all $y\in [0,1)$ there exist two elements of the domain, $z_1,z_2$ such that $y=f(z_1)=f(z_2)$. Note that if $y=0$ that $z_1=z_2=0$

Comment: I am not allowed to use calculus at all. Could please show me how I can prove $ 0\le y<1 $ using the equation I generated in the question?

Comment: @Ixion can I solve $ y\ +\ yz^2\ -\ z^2\ =\ 0 $ using the quadratic equation and then show that $ 0\le y<1 $

Comment: It's not necessary in this case, and remember that $y$ is fixed in $[0,1)$ so $0\le y<1$ is an information that you know :). You need to use such information to "win". (My english is terrible, sorry)

Comment: Could I say that $ z\ =\ \frac{+-\ \sqrt{-4\left(y-1\right)\left(y\right)}}{2\left(y-1\right)} $ using the quadratic equation? If so how does that imply that $ 0\le y<1 $

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel Yes, and that simplifies to DonAntonio's answer.

Comment: How does that simplify to DonAntonio's answer? Could you please show me

Comment: Could anyone please show me how to prove $ 0\le y<1 $ using the quadratic formula?

Comment: Focus, DonAntonio show that ${\color{red}\forall} y\in [0,1)$ exists at least one $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $y=f(x)$, so $[0,1)\subseteq f(\mathbb{R})$. You can use the quadratic formula, but it's less "elegant".

Answer (score 2):

Using your work:

$$\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}=z\implies zx^2-x^2+z=0\iff(z-1)x^2=-z\iff x=\pm\sqrt\frac z{1-z}$$

and observe the square root is well defined iff $\;0\le z<1\;$ ...

Comment: Can I solve $ y\ +\ yz^2\ -\ z^2\ =\ 0 $ using the quadratic equation or discriminant and then show that $ 0\le y<1 $ ? If so, could you please show me?

Comment: Why would you want to use the quadratic formula for a quadratic of the form $\;kx^2+c=0\;$ ??But, of course, you can if you want...

Answer (score 1):

$$ y + yz^2 - z^2 = 0 $$
$$ y = z^2(1-y) $$
$$ \frac y {1-y} = z^2$$
$$
z = \pm \sqrt{ \frac y {1-y}}
$$
Proving that $0\le y<1$ is not needed: that's what you started with. The question is: At what point in the argument above did you use that?

Note that in order that $\dfrac y {1-y}$ be a square, it needs to be nonnegative. If $y<0$ then $1-y>0$ so $\dfrac y {1-y} <0.$ And if $y > 1$ then $1-y<0$ so $\dfrac y {1-y}<0.$ In either of those cases, the fraction $\dfrac y {1-y}$ is negative and so has no real square root. And if $y=1$ then $\dfrac y{1-y}$ is not a real number. Thus it is only when $0\le y < 1$ that $\dfrac y{1-y}$ has a square root (and in fact has two, except when $y=0$). But is the assumption that $0\le y<1$ enough? In that case, as shown above, you have $\dfrac y{1-y}\ge 0.$ So that is enough.